# How to install OpenCL on system with both Intel and AMD GPUs for hashcat?

Tags: opencl

Having trouble configuring my setup for hashcat on debian.

Here's the relevant output of lshow:

```
$ lshow
*-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Skylake PCIe Controller (x16)
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:df300000-df3fffff ioport:c0000000(size=268435456)
       *-display
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=radeon latency=0

*-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: f0
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:dc000000-df0fffff ioport:b0000000(size=268435456)
       *-display UNCLAIMED
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: G98 [GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 2]
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            version: a1
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: vga_controller cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:dc000000-ddffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:df000000-df01ffffesources: irq:133 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:df320000-df33ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to install both appropriate OpenCL drivers. They'll typically appear as separate platforms with their own devices. I'd recommend using the `clinfo` program (you can install it through your package manager) to ensure all the devices are being detected.

Comment: So I installed clinfo and ran it. There's really only GEM_APERTURE errors. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Samuel could you mark the answer as accepted so that the question is shown as solved? Thanks!